# Executing a powershell script with Exchange Snap-In via PHP

Tags: php, apache, powershell, windows-server-2008, exchange-server

I'm attempting to query an Exchange server using a powershell script executed by PHP and it doesn't seem to be working. The command I'm attempting to run is:

```
powershell "Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010";"Get-CASMailbox -Identity user@example.com | fl ActiveSyncEnabled"
```

If I type that directly into the command prompt, it executes correctly and returns:

> ActiveSyncEnabled : True

When I try it in PHP:

```
$output=shell_exec('powershell "Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010";"Get-CASMailbox -Identity user@example.org | fl ActiveSyncEnabled"');
```

I get nothing. $output is set but blank. If I add "> output.txt" to the end, I get a blank text file. I'm able to run other, simpler powershell commands successfully via PHP, but not this one. The Apache service is running as the same user as when I successfully executed the script via the command prompt.

Any ideas?

I'm running:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 64-bit
- Apache 2.2.22 32-bit
- PHP 5.2.17 VC6 32-bit
- Exchange Management Console 2010

Comment: For testing purposes, I set the Apache service to run as myself. In PHP, exec('whoami') returns my domain\username, the same username I used when I successfully executed the command at the command prompt. Shouldn't this account for any permissions issues, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try adding `2>&1` at the end of the command, e.g.:

```
$output=shell_exec('powershell "Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010";"Get-CASMailbox -Identity user@example.org | fl ActiveSyncEnabled" 2>&1');
```

Sometimes, a line break at the beginning of the powershell output seems to prevent `shell_exec` printing anything else.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! It still doesn't work, but at least now I'm getting an error: `Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 2. At line:1 char:13 + Add-PSSnapin <<<<  Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010;Get-CASMail
box -Identity MAYA@mmc.org | fl ActiveSyncEnabled
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.Excha...owerShell.E2 
   010:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Ad 
   dPSSnapinCommand`

Comment: I edited my previous comment with the error I'm getting now. I also tried entering Shedal's string directly into the command prompt, and it still executes correctly, returning `AciveSyncEnabled : True`

Comment: @amay83 The error may be because it's the wrong powershell executable you're using. Refer to this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pasen/archive/2011/04/06/resolving-error-quot-no-snap-ins-have-been-registered-for-windows-powershell-version-2-quot.aspx

Comment: I modified the command as follows: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010";"Get-CASMailbox -Identity user@example.com | fl ActiveSyncEnabled" 2>&1`. It still works at the command prompt, and I still get the same error with PHP.

Comment: It seems, the problem is because the snap-in is compiled for x64 while your shell runs in a 32-bit mode. So it doesn't see the snap-in. I found a comment which suggests how you can run the shell in another mode: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#84992. Maybe it's vice-versa, though, and you need it in 32-bit mode while you run in 64-bit mode.

Comment: Looks like you're correct. When I launch c:\windows\SysWoW64\cmd.exe and enter the command there, I get the same error that I get with PHP. So I need to get PHP to use c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe instead. Is this possible? I read the comment you linked to but I'm not sure what he's talking about.

Comment: It should be possible. As I understand it, there's a windows user which IIS runs as. This user's name is either `IUSR_{Machine Name}` (in IIS 6) or just `IUSR` (in IIS 7). What you have to do is revoke this user's right on reading, executing, etc. the `cmd.exe` file from `WoW64` and then grant this user rights on the file from `System32`.

Comment: Oh wait. You're running PHP in Apache, not in IIS. Then what I said still stands, but for another user. To see this user's name, go to `Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services`, right-click `Apache` on the list and click `Properties`, then go to the `Logon` tab.

Comment: That didn't work, but thank you very much for identifying the problem! I ended up installing Apache x64 and PHP x64, which I got from here: http://www.anindya.com/. That solved the issue, and now all the 64-bit apps are playing nicely together.

Comment: I am really glad I could help :)